# How can I change the org mode TAB behavior?

Tags: org-mode

Let's say I have the following `org` file:

```
* level 1
** level 2.1
*** level 3.1.1
**** level 4.1.1.1
**** level 4.1.1.2
*** level 3.1.2
**** level 4.1.2.1
**** level 4.1.2.2
** level 2.2
*** level 3.2.1
**** level 4.2.1.1
**** level 4.2.1.2
*** level 3.2.2
**** level 4.2.2.1
**** level 4.2.2.2
```

If I fold my file completely I'll see:

[image]

Then if I press `tab` once I see:

[image]

And if I press `tab` twice I'll have:

[image]

I'd like to change the `tab` behavior of the second `tab` press. On the second press, it opens all levels of my tree, I want it to open only the second level of my tree as the following:

[image]

This way it'd never open all the tree at once... My guess is that there's an elisp function somewhere that I can change, but I don't know how to find it... How can I change the `tab` behavior to make it open only the second level on the second press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is built-in to Org mode: `S-TAB` is bound to `org-cycle-global` whose doc string says:

```
Cycle the global visibility.  For details see ‘org-cycle’.
With ‘C-u’ prefix ARG, switch to startup visibility.
With a numeric prefix, show all headlines up to that level.
```

As the last sentence indicates, you can see all headlines up to e.g. level 3, by saying `C-u 3 S-TAB`. Replacing the 3 with another number will show you headlines with level up to (and including) that number.

BTW, `TAB` does subtree cycling; `S-TAB` does global cycling: see the [Global and local cycling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Global-and-local-cycling.html) section of the Org mode manual for details. In your case above, you have a single level 1 headline, so the two are identical, but in general, this is not going to be the case.

Comment: Cool, it's a little different from what I had initially thought since `C-u number S-TAB` opens all the tree and not only the topic that is under the cursor, but it works fine for what I need. Thanks!